# Typing an unimported module

Tags: python, annotations, type-hinting, python-typing

I have a Python package that has an optional [extras] dependency, yet I want to adhere to typing on all methods.

The situation is that in my file, I have this

```py
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, datastore: Datastore):  # <- Datastore is azureml.core.Datastore
        ...

    def my_func(self):
        from azureml.core import Datastore
        ...
```

I import from within the function because there are other classes in the same file that should be imported when not using the extras (extras being `azureml`).

So this obviously fails, because I refer to `Datastore` before importing it. Removing the `Datastore` typing from the `__init__` method obviously solves the problem.

So in general my question is whether it is possible, and if so how, to use typing when typing an optional (extras) package.

Notice, that importing in the class definition (below the `class MyClass` statement) is not a valid solution, as this code is called when the module is imported

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [TYPE_CHECKING](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TYPE_CHECKING):

> A special constant that is assumed to be True by 3rd party static type
> checkers. It is False at runtime.

*It is False at runtime*: So it doesn't affect your module's behavior.

```py
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from azureml.core import Datastore


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, datastore: Datastore):
        ...

    def my_func(self):
        from azureml.core import Datastore
        ...
```

Since I want to show this in action, I will use `operator.itemgetter` as an instance because it's recognizable for type checkers, but `azureml.core` is not:

```py
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from operator import itemgetter


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, datastore: itemgetter):
        ...

    def my_func(self):
        from operator import itemgetter
        ...


obj1 = MyClass(itemgetter(1))  # line 16
obj2 = MyClass(10)             # line 17
```

Here is the Mypy error:

```
main.py:17: error: Argument 1 to "MyClass" has incompatible type "int"; expected "itemgetter[Any]"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Which shows it works as excepted.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add my two cents:

While it is certainly a solution, I consider the use of the [`TYPE_CHECKING`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TYPE_CHECKING) constant a red flag regarding the project structure. It typically (though not always) either shows the presence of circular dependencies or poor separation of concerns.

In your case it seems to be the latter, as you state this:

> *I import from within the function because there are other classes in the same file that should be imported when not using the extras*

If `MyClass` provides **optional** functionality to your package, it should absolutely reside in its own module and **not** alongside other classes that provide core functionality.

When you put `MyClass` into its own module (say `my_class`), you can place its dependencies at the top with all the other imports. Then you put the import from `my_class` inside a function that handles the logic of loading internal optional dependencies.

Aside from visibility and arguably better style, one advantage of such a setup over the one you presented is that the `my_class` module will be consistent in itself and **fail on import**, if the extra `azureml` dependency is missing (or broken/renamed/deprecated), rather than at runtime only when `MyClass.my_func` is called.

You'd be surprised how easy it is to accidentally forget to install all extra dependencies (even in a production environment). Then you'll thank the stars, when the code fails immediately and transparently, rather than causing errors at *some point later* at runtime.